# What would the best solution be for this file sharing situation?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

*This is just for my practicing and learning. Not homework, just tinkering at home.*

---

I'm building a network for the Bluth company. They have sites in New York and Boston.

What I was thinking was creating a forest newyork.bluth.com and a new root in the same forest, boston.bluth.com.

[image: logical diagram here]

Note that they are not subdomains, but separate trees in the same forest.

Now, I'm thinking of implementing a File Server at each location. With folder /newyork and /boston at each location.

The idea is that each city should have it's own parent folder but also allow certain users to view files from the other city.

*My* approach currently is to sync files from both file servers to maintain the same files at each location, but also implement a permission for a certain user group to access the other cities files.

My questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. Is this something you would see in production?
3. Should I even bother with implementing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, certainly.

> Is this something you would see in
>   production?

Yes.

> Should I even bother with implementing
>   something like this?

Depends on business needs of the company.

Hint for "How is this done?": Look into the Windows DFS service. With that, you'll be able to keep things in sync, and then for permissions, just use the appropriate standard NTFS ACLs and you'll be good to go.

Comment: For arguments sake, lets imagine that they *need* this done yesterday. :P

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting an answer to "How is this done?", but you didn't ask that. I answered the three questions in your original post...

Comment: No, but a little nudge in the right direction would be awesome of you. :) What should I be searching for? "windows server 2003 file sync" returns software I could buy to accomplish this, but I imagine WS2003 has something like this built in, correct?

Comment: Hint posted in my answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

First  I would question why you want sperate domains.  Unless you have a reason for security boundaries (and if you are replicating fiels between them it sounds like you don't) don't create seperate domains.  This will also simplify the DFS infrastructure required.  Details on DFS for 2003 is here [Overview of the Distributed File System Solution in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787066%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Lastly if this is a new infrastructure do not implement 2003 as 2008R2 has a boatload of improvements especially if you want to to DFS

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've been reading about 2008 and it seems it has a **lot** of new features. There's also Forefront which only runs on 2008 systems. I'll definitely take some time and look into it.

Comment: forefront is a brand name that covers alot of territory, endpoint protection does cover 2003 (but off the top of my head that's the only thing that does in the forfront line)